# Moving From Help Desk to Sales Engineer

Tags: interviewing, resume, sales

I've been thinking a lot about what I want to do next and what type of companies I'd like to work for, I recently applied to Jr Sales Engineer position at a large software company and the role seemed like a great opportunity. For whatever reason, they didn't pick me as their candidate.

I used [this resume](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AsniT_yYqHbXgtAcXY42er9u-oQq2g) to get my foot in the door, but as you can tell I have no sales exp other than recommending softwares to acquaintances and colleagues family and friends. I feel that this only gets me so far.

**What routes to an entry-level job as a Sales Engineer are available to someone without prior sales experience or training (e.g. classroom training? online certification? internship? highlighting analogous experience on resume)?**

Comment: What kind of sales engineer job do you want?  Do you want to work in selling a particular software, or type of software?  I would suggest, since your current job cant teach you sales. Become and expert in what ever you want to sell.  Then perhaps you can get the job based on software knowledge alone, then learn sales later.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest talking with your boss, HR, or someone in management for some ideas.   Maybe the hiring manager -- and ask them if there is anything that you could do to prepare for the position.

The alternative is to seek a sales job outside the company and go to that.    Or even perhaps get a part time sales job somewhere else and work 2 jobs.  Then next time an opening comes up you can use that experience.

Or wait for an opening and be bold.   I moved from QA to developer 20 years ago when I saw a developer get fired and I immediately walked into the manager's office and asked for the job.   He gave me a chance because he didn't feel like going through a lengthy process to hire someone.

Comment: I work at a non-profit which is about as far away from sales as you can get, but I'm very good at talking to people about tech solutions that may help them.